# Singly Linked List in C incorrect output

Tags: c, linked-list, output

So I'm doing some linked list revison and Im trying to just load a list with some numbers and then print it out. Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct stack {
   int data;
   struct stack *next;
}*stack;

stack create_s(void){
   stack s = (void*)malloc(sizeof(stack));
   s->next = NULL;

   return s;
}

void push_s(stack s, int data) {
   while (s->next != NULL) {
      s = s->next;
      }

   s->next = (void*)malloc(sizeof(stack));
   s=s->next;
   s->data = data;
   s->next = NULL;
}

void print_s(stack s) {
   if (s==NULL) {
      return;
   } 
   else {
      while (s->next != NULL) {
         printf("%d\n",s->data);
         s=s->next;
      }
   }
}

int main (void) {
   stack s = create_s();

   push_s(s,2);
   push_s(s,4);
   push_s(s,6);
   push_s(s,8);

   print_s(s);

   return 0;
}
```

My output is however:

```
-1853045587
2
4
6
```

when it should be

```
2
4
6
8
```

Is it printing the address of my struct at the beginning? Also, why is it not printing my last element?

Thanks

Comment: I am curious about why have you named a node as a stack! :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code contains several errors, but the first thing that catches the eye is that your memory allocation is already obviously broken

```
stack s = (void*)malloc(sizeof(stack));
```

You defined `stack` as a pointer type. This means that `sizeof(stack)` evaluates to pointer size and the above `malloc` allocates enough space to store a single pointer, not enough for the entire `struct stack` object. The same memory allocation error is present in `push_s` as well.

Here's some advice

1. Don't hide pointer types behind typedef names. Define your `stack` as

   ```
   typedef struct stack{
     int data;
     struct stack *next;
   } stack;
   ```

   and use `stack *` wherever you need a pointer. I.e. make that `*` visible instead of hiding it "inside" a typedef name. This will make your code easier to read.
2. Don't cast the result of `malloc`. Anyway, what is the point of casting it to `void *` when it is `void *` already???
3. Don't use `sizeof` with *types* unless you really really have to. Prefer to use `sizeof` with *expressions*. Learn to use the following `malloc` idiom

   ```
   T *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
   ```

   or, in your case

   ```
   struct stack *s = malloc(sizeof *s);
   ```

   This will allocate a memory block of appropriate size.

Also, as @WhozCraig noted in the comments, the very first node in your list is apparently supposed to serve as a "sentinel" head node (with undefined `data` value). In your code you never initialize the `data` value in that head node. Yet in your `print_s` function you attempt to print `data` value from the head node. No wonder you get garbage (`-1853045587`) as the first line in your output. Don't print the very first node. Skip it, if it really is supposed to serve as a sentinel.

Also, the cycle termination condition in `print_s` looks strange

```
while (s->next != NULL)
```

Why are you checking `s->next` for `NULL` instead of checking `s` itself? This condition will terminate the cycle prematurely, without attempting to print the very last node in the list. This is the reason why you don't see the last element (`8`) in your output.

Comment: One another issue: `create_s` creates a node with an uninitialised `data` member.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, you are right. I didn't immediately realize that `push_s` iterates to the end of the list. I kinda "assumed" that it adds to the beginig of the list.

Comment: No clue where the down vote on this answer came from either Everything here is clearly correct (+1, btw). @user3558437 is you're reading this still, [see it live](http://ideone.com/tn1ta2) for a traditional implementation. And in case you weren't aware, this isn't a stack. If anything its a *queue*.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I'm new to all this and just trying. I've taken your advice on board.

Answer (score 2):

The actual cause of the given output can be fixed by changing:

```
s=s->next;
s->data = data;
```

to

```
s->data = data;
s=s->next;
```

Comment: That is true. That will mean that an extra "sentinel" element will reside at the end of the list now. However, it is not clear what the OP's intent was (sentinel at the start or sentinel at the end?). It is also not clear what the point of having *any* sentinel element was.